# How to replace all whitespace at the start of lines with a tab?

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, whitespace

Is there a simple way to replace all whitespace at the start of lines with a single tab character?

I thought of using a loop and a `StringBuffer`:

```
String s = "some multi line text\n      foo bar\n   blah";
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s);
for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
    if (sb.charAt(i) == '\n') {
        while (sb.charAt(i + 1) == ' ')
            sb.delete(i + 1, i + 2);
        sb.insert(i + 1, '\t');
    }
}
s = sb.toString();
```

but that seems way too hard.

Comment: Still hunting for hats :P ? Questions like these shouldn't have exceptions to SO standards `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions`. Next time, please make it a "model" for all users. Also putting some explanation in your answer is "appreciated". I mean not everyone knows that `(?m)` is an inline modifier :)

Comment: @HamZa Am I *that* transparent? :) OK - code added.

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?m)^\\s+", "\t");
```

The `(?m)` flag means "carat and dollar match start and end of lines", so `^` will match the start of every line within the string.